# How to center text horizontally in a line while showing data from database with java

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, stringbuilder

I have some stories in database. With every row there are stories. I want to show stories from database with java. I am fine with showing stories from database.

My problem is I want to show some lines center horizontally. For that I added <#c> mark before the texts of that lines to make the texts center horizontally.

The database story is below like:

<#c>A Wise Old Owl

There was an old owl that lived in an oak.

Everyday he saw incidents happening around him.

Yesterday he saw a boy helping an old man to carry a heavy basket.

Today he saw a girl shouting at her mother.

<#c>The more he saw the less he spoke.

<#c>As he spoke less, he heard more.

He heard people talking and telling stories.

....

Moral of the story :

<#c>You should be observant, talk less but listen more.

<#c>This will make you a wise person.

I tried below like this.

```
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context).getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor2 = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT subject FROM work", new String[]{});
if (cursor2.getCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No Data to show", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {
        while (cursor2.moveToNext()) {
            listItem2.add(cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("subject")));
        }

        cursor2.close();
    }
```

Above code shows all the texts including <#c>. But I want to remove <#c> and also make the <#c> marked lines center horizontally.

I tried to use StringBuilder and append function. But I am unable to apply.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

I fail to understand how I will implement this.

I need your help earnestly.

Comment: You have to set the alignment of the `listItem` programmatically if a line starts with `<#c>`, remove (`replace("<#c>", "")`, maybe) the undesired part before.  A `StringBuilder` can only build up `String`s, but is not able to align them.

Comment: @deHaar actually I fail to align the listItem programmatically where the line starts with <#c>. Plz suggest.

Comment: Does the text get added to the `listItem` and is displayed (though maybe starting with `"<#c>"`)? It is this line `listItem2.add(cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("subject")));`, right?

Comment: I need to know what type this `listItem2` has, is it a `LinearLayout` or any other one or is it even a `TextView` just named `listItem2`? Those classes may have different options of setting the alignment of its content.

Comment: @deHaar It is ArrayList<String> listItem2 = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: OK, then this piece of code is not enough, please post the part where the `String` gets added to a GUI element (`TextView`, for example). An `ArrayList<String>` is neither able to align a `String` in a view container.

Comment: @deHaar I am using below to show.   Object[] mStringArray2 = listItem2.toArray();
Fragment fragment = new AFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString(AFragment.ARG_OBJECT2, (String)mStringArray2[i]);
fragment.setArguments(args);
return fragment; After that in FragmentA.java

Comment: And which part **inside** the fragment is displaying the text? Is it a `ListView` with custom list items? You probably have an adapter that handles the list item contents using a `List` as source. Please show us that part.

Comment: @deHaar After that in FragmentA.java   
((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text2)).setText(args.getString(ARG_OBJECT2)); text2 is TextView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to

1. remove the `"<#c>"` tag at the beginning of the line if there is such a tag and
2. if there was such a tag in the line, center the text in the list item

then you can try doing it like this **in the part of your code that sets the textual content of a list item**:

```
// get the TextView instance first
TextView textView = ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text2));
// then get the text in order to check if it begins with the tag
String text = args.getString(ARG_OBJECT2);
// find out if it begings with the tag
boolean beginsWithTag = text.startsWith("<#c>");

// then handle the case of a leading tag
if (beginsWithTag) {
    // replace the tag with an empty String and trim it
    text = text.replace("<#c>", "").trim(); // removes the leading tag 
    text.trim(); // removes all trailing or leading whitespaces
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}

// finally just add the text
textView.setText();
```

> Please note that I don't have your entire code and cannot test this in any suitable way. You will have to debug any errors yourself.
>   You can also shorten this code, but I think having a few lines more than necessary shows the way to do it more clearly in this case.

Comment: Now whole textView becomes in center, not the particular lines where <#c> is before . I need only to center the lines not all the text. Plz help.

Comment: @priyankanaskar I think the easiest way to achieve that is having one `TextView` per line to be shown. That will of course depend on the amount of lines, so you might have to create the entire `ListItem` programmatically. Alternative ways are show [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458718/how-to-center-a-title-in-a-textview-with-2-lines). Setting `textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);` will affect the entire content of a `TextView`.